# How does Netbeans keep track of the projects' locations?

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration, path

When you create a new Java project in [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), you get to choose where it will be stored. My question is where does Netbeans keep a refrence to such created projects?

I looked in `/etc/netbeans.conf` but I did not find any refrence to the location I choose in Netbeans GUI.

The idea behind this is to be able to package the installed Netbean app and the created projects and be able to move it to another PC. If I know where such path is kept I can create an app that update it as necessary.

The official wiki of Netbeans doesn't talk about this.

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the project groups appear under:

```
C:\Users\aedison\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans
  \modules\projectui
```

Replace `aedison` with your user name and replace `8.1` with your Netbeans version.

Hopefully that gives you a pointer in the right direction.
I would caution you against manually messing with these settings, though.
NetBeans is very very touchy. (Take backups first!)

Answer (score 1):

I may be incorrect, but have you tried looking in your NetBeans `userdir`?

According to [this page on their site](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) NetBeans stores some files in `~/.netbeans` and `~/.cache/netbeans/7.2/`

Maybe try searching there for a database or perhaps XML file describing project locations